# Constant continuous functions

Tags: analysis, continuity

Let $f : [0, 1] → R$ be continuous with $f(0) = f(1) = 0$. Suppose that for
every $x ∈ (0, 1)$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that both $x − \delta$ and $x + \delta$ belong
to $(0, 1)$ and $$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(f(x − \delta) + f(x + \delta))$$
Prove that $f(x) = 0 \  \forall x ∈ [0, 1]$

I have no idea where to start with this problem

Comment: if $f=0$ then $x-\delta$ and $x+\delta$ cannot belong to $(0,1)$..

Comment: However, Hint:
$f$ has a maximum since it is continuous. Suppose it is $>0$ and look for a contradiction

Comment: @Exodd why not?

Comment: $f$ attains its maximum on $[0,1]$. WLOG assume the maximum is positive and is attained at $x$. Then it is also attained at the two points $x-\delta$ and $x+\delta$.The set of points in which the maximum is attained is closed. But doe to this new point $x+\delta$ you can always find a point beyond its boundary. Therefore the maximum is attained on all of $[0,1]$. Since the value at $0$ and $1$ is zero, then $f$ is constant equal to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ has a global maximum on $[0,1]$, let $M = \max_{x\in[0,1]} f(x)$.

Assume $M > 0$.

$f^{-1}(\{M\})$ is a closed set so let $t_0  = \min f^{-1}(\{M\})$.

If $t_0 > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $$M = f(t_0) = \frac{\overbrace{f(t_0+\delta)}^{\le M} + \overbrace{f(t_0-\delta)}^{<M}}2 < M$$

Therefore, $t_0 = 0$ so $M = f(0) = 0$.

An analogous discussion would show that the global minimum has to be $0$.

We conclude $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle True, thanks.